# Euclidean division of $X^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

For $n\ge 2$ the euclidean division of $X^n$ by $f(X)$ (of degree 2) will be

$$X^n=f(X)q(X)+\alpha_1X+\alpha_2\tag{$*$}$$

My question is when for some matrix $A$ we are given that $f(A)=0$ would a simple substitution into $(*)$   mean that a division by zero was allowed? $$$$Thanks in advance

Comment: You are working in the ring of polynomials.  The fact that we can evaluate polynomials and get numbers (or zero matrices) has no bearing on the euclidean division you're doing.  For example, we can say that the polynomial $x^3$ divided by the polynomial $x$ equals the polynomial $x^2$; this has nothing to do with what happens if $x=0$.

Comment: @vadim123 Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome @proofy.